# How to merge columns from multiple CSV files using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, scipy

may be the answer of this question is available but I could not get proper solution and thus I am looking for the perfect solution. Suppose I have multiple CSV files (around 1500) having single column with some time series data (10,000 times or rows). The column header name is same in all CSV files. Suppose I have CSV files like:

```
aa1.csv      aa2.csv:      aa3.csv:............aa1500.csv:
datavalue   datavalue      datavalue           datavalue
    4            1             1                  2
    2            3             6                  4
    3            3             3                  8                
    4            4             8                  9


I want the output like this:


datavalue,datavalue,datavalue,datavalue,.....datavalue
4,1,1,..2
2,3,6,..4
3,3,3,..8
4,4,8,..9
```

My codes are not working and giving something else:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os
path 'F:/Work/'
files_in_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('csv')]
for filenames in files_in_dir:
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames)
    df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a')
```

If someone can help in this?

Comment: Do every such CSV files contain the same number of **rows**?

Comment: yes, every csv file has same number of rows

Answer (score 3):

You can try it the following way with a little help from numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
path 'F:/Work/'
files_in_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('csv')]
temp_data = []
for filenames in files_in_dir:
    temp_data.append(np.loadtxt(filenames,dtype='str'))

temp_data = np.array(temp_data)
np.savetxt('out.csv',temp_data.transpose(),fmt='%s',delimiter=',')
```

Comment: It is dumping the data but appended values are not same

Comment: The values in the list are different from what is being dumped.? That is not possible

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas concat function

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = []
for filenum in range(1,1501):
    dfs.append( pd.read_csv('aa{}.csv'.format(filenum)) )
print(pd.concat(dfs,axis=1).to_csv(index=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to achieve this is by creating another CSV file by merging data from existing CSV files (assuming you have the CSV files in the format `aa##.csv`)...

```
contents = []

for filenum in range(2):
    f = open('aa{}.csv'.format(filenum + 1), 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines)
    f.close()

    if contents == []:
        contents = [[] for a in range(len(lines))]

    for row in range(len(lines)):
        contents[row].append(lines[row].rstrip('\n'))
        print(lines[row])

print(contents)
f = open('aa_new.csv', 'w')

for row in range(len(contents)):
    line = str(contents[row])
    line = line.strip('[]')
    f.write(line + '\n')

f.close()
```

You can then open & display this file as you wish using pandas.

Comment: after using line.strip().splitcan getting another error - only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: getting this '22.283026666666643\n'
'21.499415555555537\n'
'20.142722222222197\n'
'0.0\n'
'13.923109213483146\n'
'9.08471160493827\n'
'12.864911460674154\n'
'2.9649911054637865\n'

Comment: where i have null values it is giving "'0.0\n'" and where i have values it is giving "'8.649526419753085\n'"

Comment: Thank you @ Melvin

Comment: Anytime @VishalSingh